# Find out specific element with unique id from json array

Tags: freemarker

I have json array & want to group weeks according to person id's as mentioned in below example. I tried code but unable to get it because i am new to free-marker code. The JSON Array as follows:-

[{"Hours":"5.500","Status":"Draft","Week":"17","person_name":"Raj","person_id":"1414"},
{"Hours":"0.500","Status":"Draft","Week":"17","person_name":"Raj","person_id":"1414"},
{"Hours":"24.500","Status":"Draft","Week":"14","person_name":"Mukesh","person_id":"1046"},
{"Hours":"7.500","Status":"Draft","Week":"15","person_name":"Mukesh","person_id":"1046"},
{"Hours":"3.000","Status":"Draft","Week":"16","person_name":"Mukesh","person_id":"1046"}]

Could please help me. The output in below foramt
for id {1046:[14,15,16], 1414:[17,17]}

Answer (score 0):

Such kind of restructuring is not something that should be done inside a template. While FTL can add together map-like values and also list-like values, it would be very inefficient to hack this together with that (it's only for very simple tasks). The entries should be already grouped before passing the data to the template.

If you must initiate this from the template, then you will need a utility Java object that has a method that does this grouping, or a `TemplateMethodModelEx` implementation that does it. Then you call that utility object from the template (like `utils.groupByPersonId(foo)` or `groupByPersonId(foo)`). Such utility objects can be exposed to the template on various ways: as part of the data-model, globally as "shared variable" through the `freemarker.tempalte.Configuration` object, or by ensuring that the utility `TemplateMethodModelEx` (or any other `TemplateModel`) class is visible for Java and then do something like `<#assign groupByPersonId = 'com.example.GroupByPersonIdMethod'?new()>` in the template.